# Class object in Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c

I am coming from Java to Objective C, and the idea of a **class object** has me wondering about similarities with Java. From the Objective C guide in Apple documentation:

> A class definition's information is compiled and recorded in data structures made available to the runtime systems. The compiler creates just one object, a **class object**, to represent the class.

So my understanding is that the class object is created for all classes that are going to be used by the program, and a class object is what is used to create objects for that class.

For comparison, does the JVM have a similar object for all classes it loads?

Comment: Java and Objective C have many similarities in structure.  They both have the concept of a class, and an Objective C protocol is pretty much an Interface.  Java was partially based on Objective C (as well as other languages).

Comment: Java's interface was derived from Objective-C's interface (informal categories and abstract classes more than the primary declaration) which is why Obj-C's interface is named "protocol" instead. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that Java was derived directly from Objective-C (no, really, it was), the runtime models of the two are quite similar.

In Java, the notion of a "Class" isn't quite as generic as it is in Objective-C.

In Objective-C, a Class is an instance of what is known as the metaclass.  For all intents and purposes, each Class object in Objective-C does exactly as you say;  it describes a particular class available in the Objective-C runtime.

The same is conceptually true of Java classes.  There is one key difference.  In Objective-C, class methods are inherited across subclasses and *more significantly* a subclass can override a superclass's class method(s).

For example, the `NSArray` class implements the `+array` class method (the '+' means "class method").  The `NSMutableArray` subclass of `NSArray` overrides `+array` to return a mutable instance instead.

`java.lang.Class` is more akin to the Objective-C runtime API;  it is the mechanism via which you introspect the classes available in the runtime.  Since Java doesn't have functional API, the API is wrapped up in an appropriately named class.  `java.lang.Class` is kinda the runtime API and the metaclass all in one.

Answer (score 4):

A comparable structure in Java would be [java.lang.Class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: Only sort of;  `java.lang.Class` is much more like the Objective-C runtime's API in that it provides the means to introspect the classes available.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a class object for each class.
That class object is the one that, at low level, is used for functions as `class_getName()`, `class_getSuperclass()`, `class_getVersion()`, `class_respondsToSelector()`. If there would be a single class object for all the classes, then those functions would return the same result for all the classes.